# Obter todos os dados de uma tabela em um JSON - Indexeddb

Tags: javascript, banco-de-dados, tabela-banco-de-dados, indexeddb

Olá! Estou precisando obter **todos** os dados de uma tabela em um JSON. (Utilizando o banco de dados Indexeddb). Como proceder?

Answer (score 1):

**Siga os Passos**

1 - Passo: [leia o site do Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/IndexedDB)

2 - Passo: Crie o banco indexedDB

```
var cidades = [
{
  "cidade":"cidadeum",
  "latitude":-25.2985296,
  "longitude":-57.6710677
},
{
  "cidade":"cidadedois",
  "latitude":-25.465034,
  "longitude":-56.0183859
},
{
  "cidade":"cidadetres",
  "latitude":-25.4933441,
  "longitude":-54.6710438
},
 {
  "cidade":"cidadequatro",
  "latitude":-24.1586759,
  "longitude":-56.636503
},
 {
  "cidade":"cidadecinco",
  "latitude":-22.5450875,
  "longitude":-55.7618963
}
];

var IDBSetting = {
    name: "indexedDBName",
    version: 1,
    tables: [{
        tableName: "cidades",
        keyPath: "seq",
        autoIncrement: true,
        index: ["cidade", "latitude", "longitude"],
        unique: [false, false, false]
    }]
};

! function() {
    console.log("indexeDB init");

    var req = indexedDB.open(IDBSetting.name, IDBSetting.version);

    req.onsuccess = function(event) {
        console.log("indexedDB open success");
    };

    req.onerror = function(event) {
        console.log("indexed DB open fail");
    };

    //callback run init or versionUp
    req.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
        console.log("init onupgradeneeded indexedDB ");
        var db = event.target.result;

        for (var i in IDBSetting.tables) {
            var OS = db.createObjectStore(IDBSetting.tables[i].tableName, {
                keyPath: IDBSetting.tables[i].keyPath,
                autoIncrement: IDBSetting.tables[i].autoIncrement
            });

            for (var j in IDBSetting.tables[i].index) {
                OS.createIndex(IDBSetting.tables[i].index[j], IDBSetting.tables[i].index[j], {
                    unique: IDBSetting.tables[i].unique[j]
                });
            }
        }
    }
}();
```

3 - Passo: addData - Adicionando os dados

```
var IDBFuncSet = {
    //write
    addData: function(table, data) {
        var req = indexedDB.open(IDBSetting.name, IDBSetting.version);

        req.onsuccess = function(event) {
            try {
                console.log("addData indexedDB open success");
                var db = req.result;
                var transaction = db.transaction([table], "readwrite");
                var objectStore = transaction.objectStore(table);
                var objectStoreRequest = objectStore.add(data);
            } catch (e) {
                console.log("addDataFunction table or data null error");
                console.log(e);
            }

            objectStoreRequest.onsuccess = function(event) {
                //console.log("Call data Insert success");
            }
            objectStoreRequest.onerror = function(event) {
                console.log("addData error");
            }
        };

        req.onerror = function(event) {
            console.log("addData indexed DB open fail");
        };
    }
}

for(var i in cidades){
   IDBFuncSet.addData("cidades",cidades[i]);
}
```

4 - Passo: getAllData - Retornando todos os dados

```
IDBFuncSet.getAllData = function(arr, table) {
    try {
        var req = indexedDB.open(IDBSetting.name, IDBSetting.version);

        req.onsuccess = function(event) {
            var db = req.result;
            var transaction = db.transaction([table], "readonly");
            var objectStore = transaction.objectStore(table);

            var objectStoreRequest = objectStore.openCursor();

            objectStoreRequest.onsuccess = function(event) {
                var cursor = event.target.result;
                if (cursor) {
                    arr.push(cursor.value);
                    cursor.continue();
                } else {

                }
            }
        };
        req.onerror = function(event) {
            console.log("getAllData indexed DB open fail");
        };
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
var cidadesArr = [];
IDBFuncSet.getAllData(cidadesArr, "cidades");

console.log(cidadesArr);
```

---

### Outro Tutorial

**Recuperar todos os dados**

Se você quiser obter todos os dados em vez de um de armazenamento de objetos, então você pode precisar usar um cursor. Aqui está outra função que faz uso de cursor para recuperar todos os dados do armazenamento de objeto:

```
function readAll() {
        var objectStore = db.transaction("customers").objectStore("customers");

        objectStore.openCursor().onsuccess = function(event) {
          var cursor = event.target.result;
          if (cursor) {
                alert("Name for id " + cursor.key + " is " + cursor.value.name + ", Age: " + cursor.value.age + ", Email: " + cursor.value.email);
                cursor.continue();
          }
          else {
                alert("Não há mais entradas!");
          }
        };     
}
```

Como você pode ver, nós implementamos o método openCursor() para cumprir o objetivo. O openCursor() é usado para iterar sobre vários registros em um banco de dados. Pode aceita vários parâmetros, tais como limitar os itens da escala, a direção que nós queremos fazer uma iteração e etc. Neste caso, nós deixamos sem parâmetros.

O próprio objeto cursor é o resultado do pedido. Temos implementar a função continue() para continuar com a iteração seguinte no circuito. Quando o laço chega ao fim, então vamos obter o alerta com o conteúdo "Não há mais entradas!".

Veja a demonstração: http://www.onlywebpro.com/demo/jquery/indexeddb.html

Fonte: http://www.onlywebpro.com/2012/12/23/html5-storage-indexeddb/

---

Existe também uma **lib** que você pode implementar com o **indexedDB**:

http://objectdb.kganser.com

---

Espero ter ajudado.